# jQuery Two Tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two tabs: login & register. It's simple, hide login section when register tab is clicked and vice versa. When I click on register tab, login section is hidden and it's working, but when I try click again on login tab, everything is messed up.

Here is code:

```
jsfiddle.net/gdc5ryqj/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a fork of your fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/fn5yjrgw/

It appears you are using bootstrap, so I would recommend using bootstrap tabs if possible and just applying your styles, but if that's not an option, here is an example (Link above to jsfiddle).

HTML:
I changed the element the tab uses to determine active state to the `<div>`, rather than the `<p>`, and put a class 'active' on the login tab to make it the one shown by default.

I added a couple of lines to your CSS at the very end:

```
/*** Additional Styles (ryantdecker) ***/
#tab-login, #tab-register {display:none;}
#tab-login.tab-active, #tab-register.tab-active {display:block;}
.login-reg-tab {}
.login-reg-tab.active p {
    color: #E76E5D;
    border-bottom: 3px solid;}
```

Lastly, the jQuery is simply removing the active and tab-active classes from the tab and panel areas respectively, and then adding them back to the appropriate ones based on the element clicked, so that the CSS takes care of the hiding and showing

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.login-button').click(function(){

        $('.login-reg-tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.login-reg-input-holder').removeClass('tab-active');
        $('#tab-login').addClass('tab-active');
    });

    $('.register-button').click(function(){
        $('.login-reg-tab').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
        $('.login-reg-input-holder').removeClass('tab-active');
        $('#tab-register').addClass('tab-active');

    });
});
```

(There are definitely ways to make this even simpler, but not without reworking the markup and classes quite a bit, and I see you have a crazy big CSS file that would probably need to be refactored.)

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to add the class for "tab-active"

```
$(".register-button").click(function () {
    if ($("#tab-login").hasClass("tab-active")) {
        $("#tab-login").removeClass("tab-active");
        if($(".login-button p").hasClass("login-reg-text-active")){
            $(".login-button p").removeClass("login-reg-text-active");}
        $("#tab-login").toggle();
    }
    if($('#tab-login').hasClass('tab-active')) {
        $('#tab-register').hide();
    }
    $("#tab-register").show();
    $(".register-button p").addClass("login-reg-text-active");
    $("#tab-register").addClass("tab-active")
});
$(".login-button").click(function () {
    if ($("#tab-register").hasClass("tab-active")) {
        $("#tab-register").removeClass("tab-active");
        if($(".register-button p").hasClass("login-reg-text-active")){
            $(".register-button p").removeClass("login-reg-text-active");}
        $("#tab-register").hide();
        //$("#tab-register").toggle();
    }
    if($('#tab-register').hasClass('tab-active')) {
        $('#tab-login').hide();
    }
    $("#tab-login").show();
    $(".login-button p").addClass("login-reg-text-active");
    $("#tab-login").addClass("tab-active")
});
```